# Why do I have to push my gpg key to ubuntu key server before using launchpad?

Tags: launchpad, gnupg

I am just starting to explore about launchpad package upload, .deb packaging and GPG keys.

One thing that bothers me is that why do I have to upload/push my gpg key to ubuntu's keyserver before using launchpad ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu's (Debian) APT package management verifies package integrity by using GnuPG, a PGP implementation. For distributing keys, the regular public PGP keyservers are used. Any public key can be uploaded there for anyone to retrieve. By comparing the fingerprints on the key(s) you mention on Launchpad and the ones on the packages everyone including Launchpad itself can verify the software is indeed uploaded by you and hasn't change since it left your machine.

Ubuntu's key servers are synchronized with other Open PGP key servers.

I don't see why you would need to be uncomfortable uploading your key as it's just the public key (of course). If you don't want to share your real name, just create a second key with another name and use that one for Launchpad/debuild.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. There is still one more thing, namely: why in 'normal' conditions you sign/encrypt a message with public key and encrypt with your private key (e.g. e-mail conversation but when it comes to packages... exactly? How does it work ?

Comment: You sign and encrypt using a private key, and you can decrypt or verify a signature using the public key. This is how asymmetrical cryptography works. I suggest you have a read at the basics on that topic in order to understand that. For example [Wikipedia: Public-key cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography)